# Should the Astronomy site pop up when someone queries for "space"?

Tags: discussion

I wanted to ask a question for the 1st image of a black hole. I searched for the right site in SE, and what better keyword for my query other than "space", right?

Space exploration site came up as the only choice, so I asked there, and they told me that the right site is Astronomy.

Should it be that Astronomy site pops up when someone queries for "space" anyway, in order for the site to be reachable by average users like me? :)

[image]

Comment: It's either searching for: the site name ("Astronomy"), the site's short name ("Astronomy.SE"), or the site's short description ("For astronomer and astrophysicists"). Do you have any proposal for solving this issue?

Comment: I thought so @GetAnswerWizard, maybe the people of that site enhancing their "thing"? I am not sure, that's I was hoping to seed the discussion here ..

Comment: Why didn't you post it on [Astronomy Meta](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/)? It seems like this question is only relevant to astronomy.SE. You even started writing a question there.

Comment: Because non-related people looking for it are more likely to be represented by users here, than there... and yes, but because I just had posted my black hole question, I had to wait 50 mins to post again, and I. The meanwhile I thought it would be nice to post it here, since it's not a trivial problem (I was already thinking of what GetAnswerWizard commented), so that everybody willing to help is going to have a chance to actually help.. :) –